# Table issues -- off page, \newline not working

Tags: tables, tabularx

[image: Desired Result]

I'm new to LaTeX and am having problems with this compiling in LaTeX the above, desired table. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{Latex File}
\author{Noob}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
\hline
\hline
Nuclide & Gamma-Ray \newline Energy (keV) & Half-Life \newline (Days) & Master\newline Source \newline ($\gamma$ps/g) & This Source \newline ($\gamma$ps) & Calibration Method \\
\hline
\hline
$^{210}\text{Pb}$ & 46.5 & 8.145E3 &  &4.596E2 & 4IILS \\
$^{242}\text{Am}$ & 59.5 & 1.580E5 &  & 3.265E2 & 4IILS \\
$^{109}\text{Cd}$ & 88.0 & 4.626E2 & 1.665E5 & 4.408E2 & HPGe \\
$^{57}\text{Co}$ & 122.1 & 2.718E2 & 8.986E4 & 2.379E2 & HPGe \\
$^{139}\text{Ce}$ & 165.9 & 1.376E2 & 1.253E5 & 3.315E2 & HPGe \\
$^{51}\text{Cr}$ & 320.1 & 2.770E1 & 4.003E5 & 1.060E3 & IC \\
$^{113}\text{Sn}$ & 391.7 & 1.151E2 & 1.746E5 & 4.621E2 & HPGe \\
$^{85}\text{Sr}$ & 514.0 & 6.484E1 & 3.070E5 & 8.127E2 & IC \\
$^{137}\text{Cs}$ & 661.7 & 1.098E4 & 1.111E5 & 2.941E2 & HPGe \\
$^{88}\text{Y}$ & 898.0 & 1.066E2 & 4.263E5 & 1.128E3 & HPGe \\
$^{60}\text{Co}$ & 1173.2 & 1.925E3 & 2126E5 & 5.628E2 & HPGe \\
$^{60}\text{Co}$ & 1332.5 & 1.925E3 & 2.127E5 & 5.629E2 & HPGe \\
$^{88}\text{Y}$ & 1836.1 & 1.066E2 & 4.513E5 & 1.195E3 & HOGe \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The issues I'm having are that

- the `\newline` command is not doing anything,
- the `\center` is not fixing the orientation of the table, which runs off the page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would typeset the table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin = 4cm]{geometry} % to avoid `overfull \hbox' warning
\usepackage[tableposition = top]{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage[version = 4]{mhchem} % use if you have more than a few chemical symbols

\newcommand*\nuc[1]{$\prescript{#1}{}{}$}
\newcommand*\elem[1]{\textup{#1}}
\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand*\lineB[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{A table with some data.}
\label{tbl:some-data}
\begin{tabular}{
  @{\hspace{0.85em}} r
  @{\hspace{0em}}    l
                     S[table-format = 4.1]
                *{3}{S[table-format = 1.3e1, exponent-product = \cdot]}
                     c
}
 \toprule
  \mc{Nuclide}          & {\lineB{Gamma-Ray\\ Energy}} & {Half-life} & {Master Source}                             & {This Source}      & {\lineB{Calibration\\ Method}} \\[2ex]
  \mc{---}              & {\si{\keV}}                  & {Days}      & {$\gamma$\si[per-mode = symbol]{\ps\per\g}} & {$\gamma$\si{\ps}} & ---                            \\
 \midrule
  \nuc{210} & \elem{Pb} &   46.5                       & 8.145e3     & {---}                                       & 4.596e2            & 4IILS                          \\
  \nuc{242} & \elem{Am} &   59.5                       & 1.580e5     & {---}                                       & 3.265e2            & 4IILS                          \\
  \nuc{109} & \elem{Cd} &   88.0                       & 4.626e2     & 1.665e5                                     & 4.408e2            & HPGe                           \\
  \nuc{57}  & \elem{Co} &  122.1                       & 2.718e2     & 8.986e4                                     & 2.379e2            & HPGe                           \\
  \nuc{139} & \elem{Ce} &  165.9                       & 1.376e2     & 1.253e5                                     & 3.315e2            & HPGe                           \\
  \nuc{51}  & \elem{Cr} &  320.1                       & 2.770e1     & 4.003e5                                     & 1.060e3            & IC                             \\
  \nuc{113} & \elem{Sn} &  391.7                       & 1.151e2     & 1.746e5                                     & 4.621e2            & HPGe                           \\
  \nuc{85}  & \elem{Sr} &  514.0                       & 6.484e1     & 3.070e5                                     & 8.127e2            & IC                             \\
  \nuc{137} & \elem{Cs} &  661.7                       & 1.098e4     & 1.111e5                                     & 2.941e2            & HPGe                           \\
  \nuc{88}  & \elem{Y}  &  898.0                       & 1.066e2     & 4.263e5                                     & 1.128e3            & HPGe                           \\
  \nuc{60}  & \elem{Co} & 1173.2                       & 1.925e3     & 2.126e5                                     & 5.628e2            & HPGe                           \\
  \nuc{60}  & \elem{Y}  & 1332.5                       & 1.925e3     & 2.127e5                                     & 5.629e2            & HPGe                           \\
  \nuc{88}  & \elem{Y}  & 1836.1                       & 1.066e2     & 4.513e5                                     & 1.195e3            & HOGe                           \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\noindent Above we have table~\ref{tbl:some-data}.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

A few suggestions:

- Use the [`siunitx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package to typeset the physical numbers and units in the table.
- Use the [`booktabs`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package to get a better thickness of -- and spacing around -- the horizontal rules.
- Use the [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package with the option `tableposition = top` to get better spacing between the caption and the table.
- Use the syntax `*{<number of columns>}{<column type>}` where possible to shorten the code.
- Structure the input code to make it look like the output to get a better overview of it.

Answer (score 1):

`\newline` won't work inside `c` column type. You can use `tabularx` and its `X` column instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}
\title{Latex File}
\author{Noob}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXXXX}
\hline
\hline
Nuclide & Gamma-Ray  Energy (keV) & Half-Life  (Days) & Master Source  ($\gamma$ps/g) & This Source  ($\gamma$ps) & Calibration Method \\
\hline
\hline
$^{210}\text{Pb}$ & 46.5 & 8.145E3 &  &4.596E2 & 4IILS \\
$^{242}\text{Am}$ & 59.5 & 1.580E5 &  & 3.265E2 & 4IILS \\
$^{109}\text{Cd}$ & 88.0 & 4.626E2 & 1.665E5 & 4.408E2 & HPGe \\
$^{57}\text{Co}$ & 122.1 & 2.718E2 & 8.986E4 & 2.379E2 & HPGe \\
$^{139}\text{Ce}$ & 165.9 & 1.376E2 & 1.253E5 & 3.315E2 & HPGe \\
$^{51}\text{Cr}$ & 320.1 & 2.770E1 & 4.003E5 & 1.060E3 & IC \\
$^{113}\text{Sn}$ & 391.7 & 1.151E2 & 1.746E5 & 4.621E2 & HPGe \\
$^{85}\text{Sr}$ & 514.0 & 6.484E1 & 3.070E5 & 8.127E2 & IC \\
$^{137}\text{Cs}$ & 661.7 & 1.098E4 & 1.111E5 & 2.941E2 & HPGe \\
$^{88}\text{Y}$ & 898.0 & 1.066E2 & 4.263E5 & 1.128E3 & HPGe \\
$^{60}\text{Co}$ & 1173.2 & 1.925E3 & 2126E5 & 5.628E2 & HPGe \\
$^{60}\text{Co}$ & 1332.5 & 1.925E3 & 2.127E5 & 5.629E2 & HPGe \\
$^{88}\text{Y}$ & 1836.1 & 1.066E2 & 4.513E5 & 1.195E3 & HOGe \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With centered columns and `booktabs` rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx,booktabs}
\title{Latex File}
\author{Noob}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
Nuclide & Gamma-Ray  Energy (keV) & Half-Life  (Days) & Master Source  ($\gamma$ps/g) & This Source  ($\gamma$ps) & Calibration Method \\
\midrule
$^{210}\text{Pb}$ & 46.5 & 8.145E3 &  &4.596E2 & 4IILS \\
$^{242}\text{Am}$ & 59.5 & 1.580E5 &  & 3.265E2 & 4IILS \\
$^{109}\text{Cd}$ & 88.0 & 4.626E2 & 1.665E5 & 4.408E2 & HPGe \\
$^{57}\text{Co}$ & 122.1 & 2.718E2 & 8.986E4 & 2.379E2 & HPGe \\
$^{139}\text{Ce}$ & 165.9 & 1.376E2 & 1.253E5 & 3.315E2 & HPGe \\
$^{51}\text{Cr}$ & 320.1 & 2.770E1 & 4.003E5 & 1.060E3 & IC \\
$^{113}\text{Sn}$ & 391.7 & 1.151E2 & 1.746E5 & 4.621E2 & HPGe \\
$^{85}\text{Sr}$ & 514.0 & 6.484E1 & 3.070E5 & 8.127E2 & IC \\
$^{137}\text{Cs}$ & 661.7 & 1.098E4 & 1.111E5 & 2.941E2 & HPGe \\
$^{88}\text{Y}$ & 898.0 & 1.066E2 & 4.263E5 & 1.128E3 & HPGe \\
$^{60}\text{Co}$ & 1173.2 & 1.925E3 & 2126E5 & 5.628E2 & HPGe \\
$^{60}\text{Co}$ & 1332.5 & 1.925E3 & 2.127E5 & 5.629E2 & HPGe \\
$^{88}\text{Y}$ & 1836.1 & 1.066E2 & 4.513E5 & 1.195E3 & HOGe \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]